# Difference between window.load and jQuery's $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript

What are the differences between JavaScript's  `window.load` and `JQuery's $(document).ready()` method? I need a function when open the page **first check JavaScript means cookies then load the HTML or body**?

Comment: window.load is when assets are fully loaded, document.ready is when DOM elements are ready to be used.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want server-side code.

Comment: The `load` event: everything's loaded. The `DOMContentLoaded` event: the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @Marciano's comment adding the network waterfall for visual depiction. [image: network waterfall for visual depiction]